# removing docker image (docker image rm don't work)

Tags: linux, docker, image, redhat

Hi after changing files names and removing and reinstalling docker (I had to choose another package)
I get a problem with removing image from older installation

```
docker container  ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

(nothing)

```
docker image list
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
linuxserver/bookstack   latest    de5fa1566aec   10 days ago   262MB
```

my attempts:

```
docker image rm linuxserver/bookstack
Error: No such image: linuxserver/bookstack

docker image rm linuxserver/bookstack:latest
Error: No such image: linuxserver/bookstack:latest

docker image rm de5fa1566aec
Error: No such image: de5fa1566aec

docker rmi -f linuxserver/bookstack:latest
Error: No such image: linuxserver/bookstack:latest

docker rmi -f linuxserver/bookstack
Error: No such image: linuxserver/bookstack

docker rmi -f de5fa1566aec
Error: No such image: de5fa1566aec
```

another idea:

```
docker system prune
```

> WARNING! This will remove:
>
> - all stopped containers
> - all networks not used by at least one container
> - all dangling images
> - all dangling build cache
>
> Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y Total reclaimed space: 0B

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
linuxserver/bookstack   latest    de5fa1566aec   10 days ago   262MB
```

overwriting

```
docker image import bookstack.docker

docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>                  <none>    47f974b4ca36   11 seconds ago   278MB
linuxserver/bookstack   latest    de5fa1566aec   11 days ago      262MB
```

my last hit

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
Error: No such image: de5fa1566aec
```

Slava Kuravsky solution

```
docker tag busybox:latest linuxserver/bookstack:latest

docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
<none>                  <none>    47f9*   2 days ago    278MB
linuxserver/bookstack   latest    de5f*   13 days ago   262MB
busybox                 latest    ff4a*   2 weeks ago   1.24MB
linuxserver/bookstack   latest    ff4a*   2 weeks ago   1.24MB

docker system prune -f
Deleted Images:
deleted: sha256:47f9****
deleted: sha256:29ef****

docker rmi -f linuxserver/bookstack:latest
Untagged: linuxserver/bookstack:latest

 docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
linuxserver/bookstack   latest    de5fa***   13 days ago   262MB
busybox                 latest    ff4a8***   2 weeks ago   1.24MB
```

Still don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to pull this image again and override the broken reference: `docker pull linuxserver/bookstack:latest`

Comment: `docker image ls 

REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>                  <none>    47f974b4ca36   11 seconds ago   278MB
linuxserver/bookstack   latest    de5fa1566aec   11 days ago      262MB`

Comment: It's well edited in original problem

Comment: You can also try to rename some existing image to bookstack: `docker pull busybox:latest; docker tag busybox:latest linuxserver/bookstack:latest; docker system prune -f; docker rmi -f linuxserver/bookstack:latest`

Comment: didn't work, all coomand and outputs are in upadated post :(